# I want to add a bearer token to my retrofit post request

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

I have an app that is to register people into a platform but I get a response of `Unauthenticated` each time I submit the form data. The form is submitted using an API which requires a bearer token for each post request with the aid of retrofit. I have been out of touch with Java.
Note: its just a plain form. No authentication has been implemented in the app.

My ApiClient.java class

```
public class ApiClient {

    private static Retrofit getRetrofit(){

        HttpLoggingInterceptor httpLoggingInterceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        httpLoggingInterceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);

        OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(httpLoggingInterceptor).build();


        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("xxxxxxxxxxxxx")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .client(okHttpClient)
                .build();

        return retrofit;
    }

    public static UserService getUserService(){
        UserService userService = getRetrofit().create(UserService.class);

        return userService;
    }
}
```

My UserService.java class

```
public interface UserService {

    @POST("algonapi/api/enroll_vehicle")
    Call<UserResponse> saveUser(@Body UserRequest userRequest);

}
```

My saveUser Method

```
public void saveUser(UserRequest userRequest){
        Call<UserResponse> userResponseCall = ApiClient.getUserService().saveUser(userRequest);
        userResponseCall.enqueue(new Callback<UserResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<UserResponse> call, Response<UserResponse> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()){
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Registration Successfull! Click on Reset Form to Start a New Enumeration...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Registration Failed!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<UserResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Registration Failed!" +t.getLocalizedMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }
```

My UserRequest

```
package com.example.xxxxx;

public class UserRequest {
    private String FullName;
    private String StickerNumber;
    private String Address;
    private String Email;
    private String Phone;
    private String Nationality;
    private String State;
    private String LGA;
    private String RC;
    private String DriversLicenseNo;
    private String LicenseIssued;
    private String LicenseExpiry;
    private String VehicleType;
    private String VehicleLicense;
    private String VehicleTyres;
    private String LGAofOperation;
    private String NOKFullName;
    private String NOKAddress;
    private String NOKPhone;
    private String NOKEmail;
    private String NOKNationality;
    private String NOKState;

  
    public String getFullName() {
        return FullName;
    }

    public void setFullName(String fullName) {
        FullName = fullName;
    }

    public String getStickerNumber() {
        return StickerNumber;
    }

    public void setStickerNumber(String stickerNumber) {
        StickerNumber = stickerNumber;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return Address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        Address = address;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return Email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        Email = email;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return Phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        Phone = phone;
    }

    public String getNationality() {
        return Nationality;
    }

    public void setNationality(String nationality) {
        Nationality = nationality;
    }

    public String getState() {
        return State;
    }

    public void setState(String state) {
        State = state;
    }

    public String getLGA() {
        return LGA;
    }

    public void setLGA(String LGA) {
        this.LGA = LGA;
    }

    public String getRC() {
        return RC;
    }

    public void setRC(String RC) {
        this.RC = RC;
    }

    public String getDriversLicenseNo() {
        return DriversLicenseNo;
    }

    public void setDriversLicenseNo(String driversLicenseNo) {
        DriversLicenseNo = driversLicenseNo;
    }

    public String getLicenseIssued() {
        return LicenseIssued;
    }

    public void setLicenseIssued(String licenseIssued) {
        LicenseIssued = licenseIssued;
    }

    public String getLicenseExpiry() {
        return LicenseExpiry;
    }

    public void setLicenseExpiry(String licenseExpiry) {
        LicenseExpiry = licenseExpiry;
    }

    public String getVehicleType() {
        return VehicleType;
    }

    public void setVehicleType(String vehicleType) {
        VehicleType = vehicleType;
    }

    public String getVehicleLicense() {
        return VehicleLicense;
    }

    public void setVehicleLicense(String vehicleLicense) {
        VehicleLicense = vehicleLicense;
    }

    public String getVehicleTyres() {
        return VehicleTyres;
    }

    public void setVehicleTyres(String vehicleTyres) {
        VehicleTyres = vehicleTyres;
    }

    public String getLGAofOperation() {
        return LGAofOperation;
    }

    public void setLGAofOperation(String LGAofOperation) {
        this.LGAofOperation = LGAofOperation;
    }

    public String getNOKFullName() {
        return NOKFullName;
    }

    public void setNOKFullName(String NOKFullName) {
        this.NOKFullName = NOKFullName;
    }

    public String getNOKAddress() {
        return NOKAddress;
    }

    public void setNOKAddress(String NOKAddress) {
        this.NOKAddress = NOKAddress;
    }

    public String getNOKPhone() {
        return NOKPhone;
    }

    public void setNOKPhone(String NOKPhone) {
        this.NOKPhone = NOKPhone;
    }

    public String getNOKEmail() {
        return NOKEmail;
    }

    public void setNOKEmail(String NOKEmail) {
        this.NOKEmail = NOKEmail;
    }

    public String getNOKNationality() {
        return NOKNationality;
    }

    public void setNOKNationality(String NOKNationality) {
        this.NOKNationality = NOKNationality;
    }

    public String getNOKState() {
        return NOKState;
    }

    public void setNOKState(String NOKState) {
        this.NOKState = NOKState;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you most of your https requests need authentication then the first answer is perfect but if some of your requests need then you can pass the header to each methods.

```
public interface UserService {
    @POST("algonapi/api/enroll_vehicle")
    Call<UserResponse> saveUser(
        @Header("Authorization") String token,
        @Body UserRequest userRequest
    );
}
```

While calling the method simply pass your token along with userRequest.

Comment: On updating the code, I started getting an error on my saveUser Method

Comment: make sure the token look like "Bearer " + token

Comment: can you show me the code how you are calling `saveUser` method?

Comment: I Have updated the code as shown above to show the `saveUser` method

Comment: Are you still with me? As I don't really know how to pass that token yet...

Comment: are you getting `token` from back end api?

Comment: Yes, I am supposed to get it from the backend api

Comment: then simply store the token somewhere & pass it to `saveUser` method as argument

Answer (score 1):

Create the `OkHttpClient` like this

```
  OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
        @NotNull
        @Override
        public Response intercept(@NotNull Chain chain) throws IOException {
            Request request=chain.request().newBuilder()
                    .addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + token)
                    .build();
            return chain.proceed(request);
        }
    }).build();
```

Comment: send the token in the getRetrofit(token) method.

Comment: How do I achieve that

Comment: send the token through the parameter when you call the method.